# switch loop into a for: why is every case true?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, switch-statement

```
for(int i = 0; i <= lvl-1; ++i) {

        id = sequence.get(i);

        switch(id) {
        case 1:
            sq1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_show);

            hnd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    sq1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square);
                }
            }, 2000);

            break;
        case 2:
            sq2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_show);

            hnd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    sq2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square);
                }
            }, 2000);

            break;
        case 3: ...
```

Do you have any idea why when this cicle is passed through, each and every one of the cases are true?
As if var "id" is 1, 2, 3 AND 4 AND 5 and every else

The code doesn't wait the 2 seconds between each loop, but gets them as true at the 1st one

Comment: I don't get it... If the for pass by every number (1... 2... 3... 4...) so every one of the cases are true...

Comment: You are using thread and doing wait on it. It just waits for thread not for the for loop.

Comment: yes, it should pass by (for ex) 5, 9, and 1. 5 (wait 2 secs) 9 (wait) 1 (wait), instead it it gives them all correct at once

Comment: what do you suggest doing JustWork?

Comment: what you do as @JustWork said you are posting all off them at once on n different threads, with same delay. You can apply small hack by setting 2000 * i at your thread post delay time. But still this is not a proper way to do it, it's just a way to wiggle around :)

Comment: Your loop runs without any delay... so all you call all postDelayed milliseconds apart, they wait 2000 milliseconds and all execute near simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah, its a delay problem. You are delaying every step 2000 milisecond at once. Remember that the postDelayed is an asynchronous call.

Comment: Because of the loop. But why have the switch at all? If you had an array `T[] sq = {sq1, sq2, ...};` you could just use `sq[sequence.get(i)]` and eliminate the switch altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I see this got a lot of attention. As JustWork said you are executing for loop and all of the cases are dealt instantly, you are just creating N threads which wait 2 seconds and then do. As I said already you can apply simple hack by adding 2000 * i at your post Delay time. Like this

```
case 1:
        sq1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_show);

        hnd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                sq1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square);
            }
        }, 2000 * (i + 1));
```

This means that you are going to create all threads at once and each is going to wait 2 seconds before it shows. i + 1 is for the time when i is zero.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Answer (score 1):

postDelayed is an Asynchronous call. Or you put a thread sleep, or you implement a notification and wait for the response, or you increment the delay each loop, like

```
int delay = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= lvl-1; ++i) {

    id = sequence.get(i);

    delay += 2000;

    switch(id) {
    case 1:
        sq1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_show);

        hnd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                sq1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square);
            }
        }, delay);

        break;
    case 2:
        sq2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_show);

        hnd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                sq2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square);
            }
        }, delay);

        break;
    case 3: ...
```

But the best solution is implement a notification handler.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is some issue with the declaration and values of the id and lvl variables. please check their values in debug mode.

Comment: lvl is set to 3 and id is set to the position i of a list of integers

Comment: the output shows that all the cases are being satisfied. it doesn't mean that in a single loop all of the cases are called. It means that for a single loop only one case is passed coz you have break statements. The issue with the code is that the loop is running long enough to satisfy each and every cases (one at a time in a loop cycle). so think more looping not more casing!!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are looping through, consider the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= lvl-1; ++i) { 
    id = sequence.get(i); // this probably returns i

    switch(id) {
    case 1:
        // this will execute during the *first* iteration of the for loop
    case 2:
        // this will execute during the *second* iteration of the for loop
    ...
    }
}
```

This is my best guess, without being able to see the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that if you want to delay your loop you must use `Thread.sleep(2000);`

But you also must use `Async` call for the for loop. And this will provide you not to lock UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't supposed to wait. The execution of the delayed `Runnable` is supposed to wait. The code in the `for/switch` just keeps running, at maximum speed.

But why have the switch at all? If you had an array `T[] sq = {sq1, sq2, ...};` you could just use `sq[sequence.get(i)].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_show)`, etc., and eliminate the switch altogether.